# Unity dual monitor wallpaper corruption

Tags: 11.04, unity

I am running 11.04. I have a Nvidia Geforce GT 240 with a dual monitor setup and am running the proprietary drivers. Each time I login, I get a weird problem. The left monitor has a corrupted background. It appears that the region where the app menu would reside is at a different zoom level than the rest of the screen.  If I do anything to cause occlusion on that part of the screen the background redraws and everything looks OK. Has anyone else experienced this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this on occasion, I think it's due to some driver problems. What I do is open a window, and then drag it over the corrupted area, it should act like an eraser and show you the normal background.

It's reported on Launchpad: [Bug #769458 Desktop background not properly drawn on login (dual monitor)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/769458)